# How do I free up space on arduino Yun shield?

Tags: shields, arduino-yun, python

I recently bought arduino Yun shield, and I didnt had any external USB storage connected, I downloaded [`get-pip.py`](https://bootstrap.py%20pa.io/get-pip.py) on Yun using wget and ran `python get-pip.py` which resulted in 5mb storage on yun now full and even pip is not installed.

how do I free up space or reset yun shield to original , and use USB storage as default location for storing all opkg and python onto USB storage drive ?